# identitys TCP outgoing connection for blackjack

Tags: networking, osx, macintosh

Using macOS X 10.14 Mojave
I have found this TCP outgoing connections for blackjack and cannot find any useful info for what it is and what for identitys daemon is using for on background
Is it safe and for it? 
How I can manage connection such kind and tell to osX avoid it ?

```
MBP:~ $ > lsof -i | grep -E "(LISTEN|ESTABLISHED)"
identitys   359 user   28u  IPv6 0x9dbd21df09361a9      0t0  TCP mbp.local:1024->[fe80:d::ab60:4498:eda8:6f41]:1024 (ESTABLISHED)
identitys   359 user   29u  IPv6 0x9dbd21df09361a9      0t0  TCP mbp.local:1024->[fe80:d::ab60:4498:eda8:6f41]:1024 (ESTABLISHED)
identitys   359 user   33u  IPv6 0x9dbd21df0935be9      0t0  TCP mbp.local:34453->[fe80:d::ab60:4498:eda8:6f41]:blackjack (ESTABLISHED)
identitys   359 user   34u  IPv6 0x9dbd21df0935be9      0t0  TCP mbp.local:34453->[fe80:d::ab60:4498:eda8:6f41]:blackjack (ESTABLISHED)
```

Answer (score 4):

`identitys` is a truncated version of `identityservicesd`, as the full name won't fit in the default output layout of `lsof`. You can look it up by taking the PID number (359 in the question post) and running `ps -fp <PID number>`. It will display the full pathname, which should be:

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/MacOS/identityservicesd
```

`blackjack` is simply a name assigned to TCP/UDP port 1025 in `/etc/services` file on Macs; it is not a reliable indication of the port's current use.

[This question in Ask Different.SE](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/356622) has more discussion on `identityservicesd`, but no actual answer yet. [Reddit suggests](https://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/6v0crs/what_is_identityservicesd/) it might be related to iCloud/iMessage/FaceTime background processing, and that conclusion would be supported by the names of some files in directory `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/identityservicesd.app/Contents/Resources`:

- `FaceTime.icns`
- `iCloud.icns`